# Add dropdown as filter in kendo-UI grid using c#

Tags: c#, filter, kendo-grid, dropdown

In my kendo-UI grid want to add dropdownlist as filter instead of textbox.
i want to do this using c# not in clientside code

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Have you searched this question before posting? Why don't you ask this on their support site?

Comment: Yes i searched it.but all answers in client side code only. I am explicitly mentioned in my question i expecting server side solution